# Lost reputation from posts I haven't touched

Tags: bug

Today I just lost reputation from questions that I haven't even answered, edited or voted. I haven't even opened these questions at all.

9 removed and 1 migrated posts all -2 reputation. Timestamp indicated that these happened all at the same time for 10 posts at **2016-11-19 02:51:20Z**.

How can I recover the reputation that I have lost?

Answer (score 8):

You did do something to all those posts: you edited them.

Below a certain reaputation threshold (2000 I believe) you receive 2 rep for each edit you do, up to a maximum of 1000 total contribution to your reputation.

As the posts you edited were most likely off-topic they got closed or migrated then subsequently deleted. As a result the 2 reputation per edit was refunded.

If a post is egregiously off topic then editing it is not helpful, it should simply be closed. For the posts that were migrated then this is an unfortunate side effect of the migration process.